# Silverlight 5 Listbox sizing

Tags: .net, silverlight, listbox, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5 Listbox inside a Star sized grid column and within the Listbox DataTemplate another Grid.

What I want to do is to fill the available space in the DataTemplate grid for the second column. As shown in the image below its only filling to the extend of the contained text.

How do I get the content to fill the available space?

```
<ListBox x:Name="TopFaultsListBox" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TopFaults, Mode=OneWay}" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedIndex="-1" Background="{x:Null}" 
            BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#FFB1925C" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="#FFE29826">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="FailureCount" Foreground="Red" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Text="{Binding FaultCount}" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AssemblyName" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding AssemblyName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="FaultInformation" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding FaultInformation}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746190/silverlight-3-listbox-datatemplate-horizontalalignment/2558348#2558348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `HorizontalContentAlignment` in the `ItemContainerStyle` of the ListBox and set it to `Stretch`. The default value is Left.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```